# WPF Binding with DataContext on Custom Content Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentcontrol, contentpresenter

I have a custom wizard control `WizardControl` deriving from `UserControl` which has a dependency property called `Pages` with a data type of my custom class collection called `WizardPageCollection`.

The `WizardControl` is hosted in a `Window` with a view model called `MainViewModel` and the pages of the wizard instantiated using XAML.

I am trying to bind the pages to sub-view models `Page1VM` and `Page2VM` declared as properties on the `MainViewModel`.

The first page binding of `DataContext` to `Page1VM` works fine, however the binding of the second page fails with the following error message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:Path=Page2VM; DataItem=null; target element is 'MyPage' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

Q. Why does the binding work on the first page but fail on the second and is there a way I can get this to work whilst still keeping the `MainViewModel` declared within the `DataContext` XAML tags of `MainWindow`?  I would prefer not to use the ViewModel as a dictionary resources as this has some implications for us which I won't go into detail about.

As suggested by a commentor, if I change the binding to use RelativeSource as follows:

```
<common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Page1VM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
<common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Page2VM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

The first binding works ok, but the second one still fails, but with a different error message (as expected):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Page2VM; DataItem=null; target element is 'MyPage' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

Thanks for your time!

My code listing is shown below:

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <common:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <common:WizardControl>
        <common:WizardControl.Pages>
            <common:WizardPageCollection>
                <common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding Page1VM}" />
                <common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding Page2VM}" />
            </common:WizardPageCollection>
        </common:WizardControl.Pages>
    </common:WizardControl>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel and PageViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public PageViewModel Page1VM
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PageViewModel Page2VM
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Page1VM = new PageViewModel("Page 1");
        this.Page2VM = new PageViewModel("Page 2");
    }
}

public class PageViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public PageViewModel(string title) { this.Title = title; }
}
```

WizardControl XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" x:Name="contentPage"/>
</Grid>
```

WizardControl code-behind:

```
public partial class WizardControl : UserControl
{
    public WizardControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public WizardPageCollection Pages
    {
        get { return (WizardPageCollection)GetValue(PagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PagesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Pages", typeof(WizardPageCollection), typeof(WizardControl), new PropertyMetadata(new WizardPageCollection(), new PropertyChangedCallback(Pages_Changed)));

    static void Pages_Changed(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WizardPageCollection col =  e.NewValue as WizardPageCollection;
        WizardControl ctrl = obj as WizardControl;
        ctrl.contentPage.Content = col.First();
    }
}

public class WizardPageCollection : ObservableCollection<WizardPageBase> { }

public class WizardPageBase : ContentControl { }
```

MyPage XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Title}"   />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Have you tried using a `RelativeSource` binding to bind to the `Window`?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I've changed the DataContext binding to use RelativeSource (the first page binding works ok, however the second page binding still fails, but the error message is slightly different).  I have updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Source files can be found at GitHub: https://github.com/dotnetdeveloper53/WizardControlBinding

Comment: Do you have the code which switches pages inside the WizardControl?

Comment: I haven't provided this code as I felt this was irrelevant to the binding problem.  However, when I do change the "Current Page" on the wizard (simply by setting `contentPage.Content = newPage`) the `DataContext` on that new page is set to `NULL` - which makes sense as the binding failed.

Comment: I have been able to successfully declare `MainViewModel` as a dictionary resource and then reference the sub-view model properties as follows (it works on both the first and second pages):
`<common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding Page2VM, Source{StaticResource mainViewModel}}" />`.  Therefore I don't understand why the static resource binding works and the inherited `DataContext` binding from `Window` doesn't (like in my example).  I would really like to be able to get the `Window.DataContext` binding working instead, simply due to a limitations of the 3rd party VM we're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach depends on the [value inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.100).aspx) of the Window's `DataContext` property, which doesn't work with your WizardPageCollection because it doesn't form a WPF element tree.

You should instead create your MainViewModel as a resource, and then reference it by `StaticResource`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <common:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource MainViewModel}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <common:WizardControl>
            <common:WizardControl.Pages>
                <common:WizardPageCollection>
                    <common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding Page1VM,
                                       Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}"/>
                    <common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding Page2VM,
                                       Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}"/>
                </common:WizardPageCollection>
            </common:WizardControl.Pages>
        </common:WizardControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and for explaining the limitation of what I was trying to achieve.  Declaring a binding on the DataContext will still allow be to bind elements to the MainViewModel, simply using `Property="{Binding Path=VM_Property}"`.

Answer (score 0):

@Clemens answer workarounds the problem but the problem is something else, imho.

1. When item is added to WizardPageCollection, it should be added to LogicalTree as well. Look at sources of ItemsControl for inspiration. It is definitelly possible to make your binding works as they were.
2. I would use viewmodel first approach here. Define pages as collection of page viewmodels and genereate the views. At the end the xaml would look like this:

   ```
   <common:WizardControl PagesSource="{Binding Pages}">
       <common:WizardControl.PageTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding }" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </common:WizardControl.PageTemplate>
   </common:WizardControl>
   ```

alternativelly, consider your `WizardControl` derive from `Selector` class instead usercontrol. (Selector is base class from listbox. It has itemssource and selected item).

```
    <common:WizardControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPage}">
        <common:WizardControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <common:MyPage DataContext="{Binding }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </common:WizardControl.ItemTemplate>
    </common:WizardControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - although the example I provided only used `MyPage` the pages which are declared could be of different types but all derived from the `WizardPageBase` class - the `DataTemplate` simply won't be one consistent visual layout.  I see that you're `PagesSource` and `ItemsSource` are binding to VMs, but how would I bind these to different types of pages - not just one?

Comment: In that case, you can use different pageviewmodel classes and use implicit datatemplates (foreach pageviewmodel class different datatemplate). If you want to have just one pageviewmodel class and choose view based on some property, you can use datatemplate selector.